# How do I count the number of bombs in my Minesweeper code?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

So well I tried creating a simpler Minesweeper game and I encountered one main problem..
I am not able to count the number of bombs and print it in a `JTextField`
Any ideas as to how to count these as I'm setting a random value to check whether they are a bomb

Tried counting it in the `ActionListener` but the bombs were counted only after the button was clicked.

```
     if(e.getSource()==b[i][j])
        {
            b[i][j].setVisible(false);

            tf[i][j].setVisible(true);
            int r1 = rand.nextInt(6);
            if(r1>1)
            {
                tf[i][j].setText("Safe");
                tf[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);

            }
            else    
            {   count++;
                tf[i][j].setText("Bomb");
                tf[i][j].setBackground(Color.red);
                f.setVisible(false);
                restart.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you determining whether or not it's a bomb on the fly or beforehand?

Comment: @Bakna I am determining it at run time as I'm not quite sure as to how to do it before hand

Comment: Really not in any way different. You have to mentally separate your "data" and the way you are displaying your data. Your data should be some form of "grid" (which could be a two dim array, but also a just a single list of tiles). And for each tile you know right from the beginning what is behind it. The whole point of minesweeper is that you know right from the beginning how many mines are in the game, and where exactly they are. So: first write code that does nothing but build that list or 2d array.

Comment: To do that: start with an empty list/array. Then *randomly* put X bombs into list/array. Then **compute** for each non-bomb tile the number of "bomb" neighbours. Both things (has bomb, number of bomb neighbors) will NOT change over the course of the game. You can even print that array/list to the console ... you dont need a GUI for that part at all.

Comment: And then, when that part works, then you think how you can use your GUI to display that data. And then when that part works, you can start adding mouse/action listeners and so on. You are trying to implement things all at once, that makes everything much harder: when you do "everything at once"; of course everything has to work in order to be testable, and work together.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the input. Will definetly try writing it like that. The idea of building the bomb part first did not occur to me.

Comment: That is a general thing in IT: whenever you can compute things upfront, and then they can stay as they are ... then you go for that. Strive to make all your fields private final: init them once, and then operate on them. Sure, some elements need to change over time. But anything else: prepare it, and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you decide if the the tile will be a bomb in the run-time using a random generator. Doing this you can't really know how many mines are in your game. I think you should decide the number of mines at the beginning of the game and randomly place them to your game board (you can choose the number according to a difficulty level).

**EDIT**

You can create a list with some random points that contain the mines

```
    int numOfMines =  10;

    int rows=5,columns=5;


    ArrayList listWithMines = new ArrayList();

    while(listWithMines.size()<numOfMines) {

        int randRow = random.nextInt(rows);
        int randCol = random.nextInt(columns);

        Point point = new Point(randRow, randCol);

        if(listWithMines.contains(point))
            continue;
        else
            listWithMines.add(point);
    }
```

This list now contains the Points that have the mines.
You can check if Point(x,y) has a mine like this:

```
if(listWithMines.contains(new Point(1, 2))) {...}
```

Instead of a list you can use a 2D array, store a boolean value (or int if you store more states) and make a loop until you place 10 mines. You should keep a counter(placedMines like the list.size()) of the mines you placed and make sure you don't add a mine to a tile that has already a mine and you increase the counter(placedMines) until it reaches the numOfMines.

Comment: I tried doing this but I was unable to set it correctly. The problem was setting it as bomb before hand and using that in the actionlistener to check for the bomb condition. It did  not work for some reason

Comment: Why? What was the problem ? Did you have access to the table variable in the listener ?

Comment: The problem is I have set the buttons (added to the frame) using two dimmensional array. I declared the bomb counter as a single dimmensional array. `for(int i = 0 ; i < rows*columns ; i++)
   {
    l[i]=  rand.nextInt(6);
   }
  for(int i = 0 ; i < rows*columns ; i++)
  {
   if(l[i]<2)
   {
    count++;
    x[i]=1;
   }
   else
    x[i]=0;
  }`

Comment: thanks a lot!! it finally worked. The idea of creating a 2D array with boolean value worked perfectly!!